# Flutter for loop causes laggy loading animation

Tags: flutter, dart

I build a for loop in Flutter on which I make some stuff with many images:

```
for (var i = 0; i < resultList.length; i++) {
  File imageFile = await _getImageFileFromAssets(resultList[i]);

  final appDir = await syspath.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  final fileName = path.basename(imageFile.path);

  final savedImage =
      await File(imageFile.path).copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');

  // Creating thumbnails

  final thumb =
      image.decodeImage(File(savedImage.path).readAsBytesSync());
  final thumbImage = image.copyResize(thumb, width: 500);

  new File('${appDir.path}/$fileName-thumb-500.jpg')
      .writeAsBytesSync(image.encodeJpg(thumbImage));

  final finalThumbImage =
      File('${appDir.path}/$fileName-thumb-500.jpg');

  picturesData.add(Picture(
      album: albumID,
      path: savedImage.path,
      thumbPath: finalThumbImage.path,
      timestamp: Timestamp.now()));

  setState(() {
    loadingScreen = true;
  });
}
```

While the loop is working, I show a loading screen Widget with an loading animation:

```
return loadingScreen == true ? LoadingScreen() : Scaffold()
```

**What I expect** A clean loading screen while the for loop duration with smooth animation

**What I get** Extreme flickering and lagging on the animation. After each image was edited, the animation stops. So I get something like a stop motion animation.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: `writeAsBytesSync` blocks your UI thread - thats why animations are flickering

Comment: I understand. Is there a workaround to make a smooth animation possible despite a writeAsBytesSync function?

Comment: no, there is not, simply do not use "*Sync" `File`'s methods

Comment: What about compute()?

Comment: what about `writeAsBytes`? `compute` would work too but its like shooting a fly with a canon

Comment: Thanks very much. I took a look what’s “sync” does and right.. I should use writeAsBytes here definitely. Thank you 

Comment: naturlich ;-), your welcome

Comment: :-))) Maybe an additional question: This for loop is only a part of a very large function. There I working with these images, do different things, load more files like audio for example and then I create a video file with `ffmpeg`. Would it make sense to put this big function into a `compute()`? Actually for 85 images it could take 1-2 minutes until the function is completed. Or it is not required / recommended / necessary?

Comment: `"[...] and then I create a video file with ffmpeg"` - so now it is not a fly, its like 500 pounds gorilla, use a canon then ;-) but when using `compute()` you will not be able to give any feedback / progress to the UI thread (but i am not 100% sure though...)

Comment: Haha. Great and clear answer! Then I will load the `cannon()` now :-) Regarding the feedback / progress in the UI thread I have to check it. This would be important. :)

Comment: Btw: I changed the function from the main thread to `writeAsBytes `, but my animation is still laggy :/ If I change `readAsBytesSync` to `readAsBytes` I get a type error. Could be another process block my UI thread?

Comment: oh, i overlooked `readAsBytesSync` - what "type error"? did you `await` for it?

Comment: `The argument type 'Future<Uint8List>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>'`

Comment: so you did not `await` for it

Comment: Oh, I see! Perfect, no errors now. But.....still a laggy animation.. :/

Comment: so...... load the `canon()` - or alternatively to `compute` you can use raw `Isolate` stuff but it is "high school"

Comment: Would this be interesting for me? https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate :-)

Comment: never used that - instead i found `IsolateChannel` class quite handy

Comment: also https://pub.dev/packages/isolate_handler or https://pub.dev/packages/isolate looks good

Comment: I tried with `compute()`, but... I can pass only one argument..therefore I pass a map as argument. But if I do this, the entire function will be ignored.. I´ve opened another topic for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967978/compute-in-flutter-has-no-effect Thanks, you helped me a lot! :)