# compute() in flutter has no effect

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to use `compute` in Flutter. Here I try to pass multiple parameters inside a Map. But the code in my function `myFunction` does not work. I get no errors or something else. My code seems to be ignored. Do you find an error here?

**Compute function:**

```
Map map = Map();
map['resultList'] = resultList;
map['_getImageFileFromAssets'] = _getImageFileFromAssets;
map["picturesData"] = picturesData;
map["albumID"] = albumID;

await compute(myFunction, map);
```

**Calls the following function:**

```
Future<bool> myFunction(map) async {
  var resultList = map["resultList"];
  var _getImageFileFromAssets = map["_getImageFileFromAssets"];
  var picturesData = map["picturesData"];
  var albumID = map["albumID"];

  print("Starten");

  for (var i = 0; i < resultList.length; i++) {
    print(i);
    File imageFile = await _getImageFileFromAssets(resultList[i]);

    final appDir = await syspath.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    final fileName = path.basename(imageFile.path);

    final savedImage =
        await File(imageFile.path).copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');

    // Creating thumbnails

    final thumb = image.decodeImage(await File(savedImage.path).readAsBytes());
    final thumbImage = image.copyResize(thumb, width: 500);

    new File('${appDir.path}/$fileName-thumb-500.jpg')
        .writeAsBytes(image.encodeJpg(thumbImage));

    final finalThumbImage = File('${appDir.path}/$fileName-thumb-500.jpg');

    picturesData.add(Picture(
        album: albumID,
        path: savedImage.path,
        thumbPath: finalThumbImage.path,
        timestamp: Timestamp.now()));
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Code gets ignored as in you don't even get the print('Starten') on your console?

Comment: Yes. It will be completed ignored..

Comment: Hm ... works for me.

Comment: is `_getImageFileFromAssets` a callback function? if so, you cannot pass it to your `myFunction()` function - see `compute(0` docs, they say: *"There are limitations on the values that can be sent and received to and from isolates. These limitations constrain the values of Q and R that are possible. See the discussion at SendPort.send."*

Comment: Thanks pskink. You´re a genius! Yes, this is a callback function. What a pity! Would I have the same limitations with isolate? Or would be possible in my case?

Comment: but why do you need to pass that callback? cannot you use the function directly? also if you want to have some progress feedback take a look into `IsolateChannel` (imho the easiest way of working with isolates), something like https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/symDQ7zcyx/

Comment: I will try it soon and write you back 

Comment: I tried it, and I figured out what the problem is. If I remove the callback from the Map, the function works in general. But my for loop will stop. For example on the first step: `final byteData = await resultList[i].getByteData();` This seems to not work for top level functions. But how can I work on complex things if I cannot use typical dart or flutter functions like `.getByteData()`? Is this normal or is the issue something else?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, some code - I put this in [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/536540b5075382941b7f4b823b114181):

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

void main() {
  Map map = Map();
  compute(myFunction, map).then((result) => print(result));
}

Future<bool> myFunction(Map map) async {
  print("Starten");
  // fake long process
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
  return true;
}
```

and get this as a console result:

```
Starten
true
```

Also: is there a reason you need the "map" parameter in your function to be `dynamic`? If not, I'd declare it as type `Map` (like I did now).

Comment: I tried it, and I figured out what the problem is. If I remove the callback from the Map, the function works in general. But my for loop will stop. For example on the first step: `final byteData = await resultList[i].getByteData();` This seems to not work for top level functions. But how can I work on complex things if I cannot use typical dart or flutter functions like `.getByteData()`? Is this normal or is the issue something else?

Comment: Have you tried just using Futures instead of compute(), then see where the bottleneck is (if there is any) and only let that particular piece of code run in an Isolate?